# Get all captured groups in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a single word inside brackets(including the brackets), my `Regex` below is working but it's not returning me all groups.

Here's my **code:**

```
String text = "This_is_a_[sample]_text[notworking]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[([a-zA-Z_]+)\\]").matcher(text);                                     
if (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
}
```

Also I've tested it in [Regex Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRjqst8hDA/index.html) and it seems to work.

It must return 4 groups:

```
------------------------------------
Group 0: [sample]
------------------------------------
Group 1: sample
------------------------------------
Group 2: [notworking]
------------------------------------
Group 3: notworking
```

But it's returning just it:

```
------------------------------------
Group 0: [sample]
------------------------------------
Group 1: sample
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

JAVA does not offer fancy global option to find all the matches at once. So, you need `while loop` here

```
int i = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
   for (int j = 0; j <= matcher.groupCount(); j++) {
      System.out.println("------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(j));
      i++;
   }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/5kKXiA)**

Comment: Hmm, I got it, my intention was to get the captured groups in reverse, in other words, from the last to the first, do you know a way to do this?

Comment: @developer033 do you want `sample` and then `[sample]`?

Comment: I want `notworking`, `[notworking]`, `sample` and `[sample]`. That's why I want collect all the captured groups, understand me now?

Comment: @developer033 put all the results in an arraylist or array and reverse it..that will be most simple approach

Comment: @developer033 by default, regex engine searches from left to right.it will be tricky to match from right to left..the approach of reversing will be most simplest one

Comment: Yes, I thought about using List before.. Thanks.

Comment: Note that using the "If" (instead of "while) will only work for the first match.

Answer (score 9):

Groups aren't thought to find several matches. They are thought to identify several subparts in a single match, e.g. the expression `"([A-Za-z]*):([A-Za-z]*)"` would match a key-value pair and you could get the key as group 1 and the value as group 2.

There is only 1 group (= one brackets pair) in your expression and therefore only the groups 0 (always the whole matched expression, independently of your manually defined groups) and 1 (the single group you defined) are returned.

In your case, try calling `find` iteratively, if you want more matches.

```
int i = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match " + i + ": " + matcher.group(1));
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also if you know the amount of matches you will get, you can find groups and add them to list then just take values from list when needed to assigned them somewhere else

```
 public static List<String> groupList(String text, Pattern pattern) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        list.add(matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    return list;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact amount of matching groups, with java 9 or later it could be done like this:

```
    String text = "This_is_a_[sample]_text[notworking]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\w*)\\]");
    List<Pair<String, String>> result = pattern.matcher(text).results()
            .map(matchResult -> Pair.of(matchResult.group(0), matchResult.group(1)))
            .toList();
```

[image]